# Extracting a resource file from library jar, while building the war app

Tags: maven, gwt, jar, resources, war

REFACTORING LIKE A SURGEON, SLOWLY SLOWLY
- On my free time, I am trying to refactor a monolith gwt-app into many apps for scaleability purposes.
- The problem is, improvements requets for the active monolith app keeps coming. So development of it should not be stopped too.

MY REFACTORING PLAN
1) Categorizing general purpose classes into projects prefixed with "api-*" -> done in 2 years.
2) Trying to create "lib-*" sub projects so, a same named later "app-*" projects can use sub project classes too - done but.. not scalable much... inprogress
3) Then trying to write many "app-*" projects that uses "lib-*" and "api-*" projects.
4) Removing the functionalty of monolith about working "app-*" projects

THE PROBLEM ABOUT CARRYING RESOURCE INSIDE LIBRARY CLASSES
My first app happens to be "app-login" and it uses a library called "lib-resource".
With my limited understanding of "pom.xml" files...
- On "lib-resource" project, when I put a file into "src\main\resources\" directory, It has builed just the root folder of jar file "target\lib-resource-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" successfuly.
- On "app-login-server" sub project, when I put a file into "src\main\resources\public" directory, It has builed just the root folder of the war file "target\app-login.war\" successfuly.
- However my "lib-resource" files is living under the location "app-login.war\WEB-INF\lib\lib-resource-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\", hence when deployed they are stucked inside the jar file.

SOLUTION SUGGESTIONS
1) Can i export a file from a library jar. 
- The problem about is I am not running a jar file. so I cannot use a trick like getClass().getResource. 
- Exporting zip files is not working in java in my two servers Windows Server 2003. So I am using java, bat files and 7z.exe combination. It is just... messy
2) If possible, can all my "lib-*" resource files defined as dependency on "app-login" project, extracted and build by maven?

RELEVANT FILES:
"lib-resource\pom.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-resource</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-gui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <resources> 
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

"app-login\pom.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-login</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <launcherDir>${basedir}/app-login-server/target/classes/launcherDir/</launcherDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>15</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceLevel>11</sourceLevel><!-- gwt cannot compile up -->
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                        <warName>app-login</warName>
                        <outputDirectory>D:\xampp\tomcat\webapps</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>app-login-client</module>
        <module>app-login-shared</module>
        <module>app-login-server</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

"app-login-client\pom.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-login</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app-login-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>gwt-app</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-login-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-login-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-bloated</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <moduleName>com.tugalsan.app.login.App</moduleName>
                    <moduleShortName>app</moduleShortName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

"app-login-server\pom.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-login</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app-login-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-login-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed if you are using GWT-RPC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-bloated</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app-login</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/public/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- XXX: We want to exclude app-login-client from 'env-dev' profile, Maven forces us to make a 'env-prod' profile -->
            <id>env-prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>app-login-client</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>env-dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

"app-login-shared\pom.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-login</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>app-login-shared</artifactId>

    <dependencies>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

On the last minute I saw that "lib-resource" project is under "lib-bloated" please find it as below
"lib-bloated\pom.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-bloated</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-resource</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-domain</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-rql</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-login</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-license</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <resources> 
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, I found a way to list all library jars inside WEBINF directory AND I found a way to see files inside jar file AND filter only resource file...    Now trying extract...  Will come when i implement a decent code

Answer (score 0):

For the people who does not use Windows Server 2003, here is the answer.
*I have used some utility functions, but it will give you the idea*

In your **public class AppServlet implements ServletContextListener** class,
you have to get your app path by...

```
var pathApp = evt.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

It will return a path like **D:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\app-login**

Then, you can construct a path to you lib directory.

```
var pathLibs = Path.of(pathApp.toString(), "WEB-INF", "lib");
```

Then, you need to get sub files according to your need. *(I have a utility class to do that)*

```
var pathLibJars_lib = TS_DirectoryUtils.subFiles(pathLibs, "lib-*-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", false, false);
```

Then, you can explode your jars into your desired resource folder. *(I have another utility class for unziping. Basicly it uses 7z.exe.)*

```
pathLibJars_lib.forEach(p -> { 
    var label = TS_FileUtils.getNameLabel(p).replace("-1.0-SNAPSHOT", ""); 
    TS_FileZipUtils.unzipFile(p, Path.of(pathApp.toString(), "res", label)); 
});
```

As an improvement, Cleanup code required because all jar files contents are exploding into **"D:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\app-login\res[jarname]** folder

Or, Rather than exploding all files, 7z parameters can be tuned to only explode res folder from the jar files

I would appricate if someone could able to do that in maven automatically rather then java.